# Committed image from container which has virtuaenv is not working

Tags: python, docker, virtualenv

Creating a custom base image with airflow installed on it with virtual environment. Image is running fine. But committed image is not working.

I tried online but couldn't find a solution.

1) Committed an image which was created with below steps running successfully with localhost:8080.

```
virtualenv launch-airflow
source launch-airflow/bin/activate
```

Install apache airflow

```
mkdir ~/airflow
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
pip3 install apache-airflow[all]==1.10.4 --no-deps 

pip3 install apache-airflow[contrib]==1.10.4
pip3 install apache-airflow[postgres]==1.10.4
pip3 install apache-airflow[celery]==1.10.4
airflow initdb
```

2) Pushed to Docker Hub.

3) Pulled from Docker.

4) Ran with the below command to start.

docker run -d -p 8080:8080 myimage:version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker commit` is a fairly limited command.  It leads to non-reproducible builds, and you can't specify key parts of the image metadata like the default command to run.  I'd highly recommend *never* running it at all.

The steps you show, though, are about 95% of a working Dockerfile.  Let's build it out, also referring to the [Airflow Quick Start](https://airflow.apache.org/start.html) along the way.  This is a Python-based application, so we can start from [the standard Docker Hub `python` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python)

```
FROM python:3.7
```

In Docker you generally don't use a Python virtual environment, since the Docker image itself is a form of isolation.  That means you can just install the packages into the "system" Python package space (isolated inside the container)

```
RUN pip3 install \
  apache-airflow[all]==1.10.4 \
  apache-airflow[contrib]==1.10.4 \
  apache-airflow[postgres]==1.10.4 \
  apache-airflow[celery]==1.10.4
```

The next step here is "initialize the database".  This is tricky, though, because in Docker generally you run a database in a separate container.  A standard trick here is to write a shell script that does first-time initialization, and then runs the main container process

```sh
#!/bin/sh
airflow initdb
exec "$@"
```

The Docker startup has two parts, an *entrypoint* and a *command*.  If you specify both, then the entrypoint gets run with the command passed as arguments.  In the script above, `exec "$@"` replaces the script with whatever the command-line arguments specify.  So, we need to copy this script into the image, set it as the entrypoint, and set the main Airflow server as the main command.

```
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["airflow", "webserver"]
```

Now you can build and run this

```
docker build -t myname/airflow:1.10.4 .
docker run --name airflow-server -p 8080:8080 myname/airflow:1.10.4
```

The quick start also suggests running a scheduler.  You can replace the `CMD` by just adding extra arguments at the end of the `docker run` command, so, for example

```
docker run --name airflow-scheduler myname/airflow:1.10.4 airflow scheduler
```

(As an exercise, PyPI tells me there is [apache-airflow](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/) 1.10.5 now.  Can you update your committed image to have the newer revision of Airflow?  Can you update the Dockerfile?)